# Get Latest SQL Query Clarification

Tags: sql

I stole this query below from this thread [Retrieving the last record in each group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group) :

```
SELECT m1.*
FROM messages m1 LEFT JOIN messages m2
 ON (m1.name = m2.name AND m1.id < m2.id)
WHERE m2.id IS NULL;
```

Could someone please help me understand how `AND m1.id < m2.id` returns the correct result/ I thought it should be `AND m1.id > m2.id` which doesn't return correct result.

I'm sort of wondering technically id should be greater.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for instances that don't join, given `WHERE m2.id IS NULL`.

Consider the following pairs of id's:

```
m1_id  m2_id
1      1
2      2
3      3
```

Using `m1.id < m2.id` without your `WHERE` criteria gets you:

```
m1_id  m2_id
1      2
1      3
2      3
3      NULL
```

- 1 is not less than 1, but it is less than 2 and 3, so 1 joins to multiple records.
- 2 is not less than 1 or 2, but it is less than 3, so 2 joins to 1
  record.
- 3 is not less than any of the records, so it does not join. It
  returns `NULL` which is the criteria you're looking for in your
  `WHERE` clause.